# Python: array as an argument for a function

Tags: python, arrays, function, input, arguments

I wanted to know how to work with an array as a functional argument in Python. I will show a short example:

```py
def polynom(x, coeff_arr):
    return coeff_arr[0]+ coeff_arr[1]+x +coeff_arr[2]*x**2
```

I obviously get the error that 2 positional arguments are needed but 4 were given when I try to run it, can anybody tell me how to do this accept just using (coeff_arr[i]) in the argument of the function?
Cheers

Comment: call it with a list like: `polynom(1, [2, 3, 4])`

Comment: or change it to this: `def polynom(x, *coeff_arr)` ;)

Comment: "I obviously get the error that 2 positional arguments are needed but 4 were given when I try to run it" That is not obvious. Please show how you run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is missing the code you use to call the function, but from the error I infer that you are calling it as `polynom(x, coefficient1, coefficient2, coefficient3)`. Instead you need to either pass the coefficients as a list:

```
polynom(x, [coefficient1, coefficient2, coefficient3])
```

Or use the unpacking operator `*` to define the function as follows, which will take all positional arguments after `x` and put them into `coeff_arr` as a list:

```
def polynom(x, *coeff_arr):
```

(The unpacking operator can also be used in a function call, which will do the opposite of taking a list and passing its elements as positional arguments:

```
polynom(x, *[coefficient1, coefficient2, coefficient3])
```

is equivalent to

```
polynom(x, coefficient1, coefficient2, coefficient3)
```

)

Comment: Thanks you very much. I first obtained the coeff_arr using the curve_fit() function of scipy on my data and then called the function using polynom(x, coeff_arr).